# Google spreadsheet script to calculate the last weekday

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-docs

I've a Google sheets script where I try to find yesterday's date as a workday by subtracting 1 from today's date.

```
  //Get today's date
  var today = new Date();

  //Take today's date and subtract 1 making yesterday's date
  var yesterday = new Date(today.getTime()-1 * (24*3600*1000));
```

The problem I face is that on a Monday it will return a Sunday, rather than a Friday. 
I tried to use the Workday function to fix the issue but I am getting some not defined errors.

```
var yesterday = new Date(WEEKDAY((today.getTime()-1 * (24*3600*1000)));
```

What would be the best method for fixing the issue?

Comment: Have you taken a interested in =WORKDAY.INTL(), the standard GS function? It lets you define which days of the week are workdays

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with using it in a script. We use the scripts for handling bulk edits to the sheets.